# resample time series on uniform interval in numpy/scipy?

Tags: numpy, scipy

I have a random variable `X` sampled at random times `T` similar to this toy data:

```
import numpy as np
T = np.random.exponential(size=1000).cumsum()
X = np.random.normal(size=1000)
```

This timeseries looks like this:
[image]

A key point is that the sampling interval is non-uniform: by this I mean that all elements of `np.diff(T)` are not equal. I need to resample the timeseries `T,X` on uniform intervals with a specified width `dt`, meaning `(np.diff(T)==dt).all()` should return `True`.

I can resample the timeseries on uniform intervals using `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`, but this method does not allow me to specify the interval size `dt`:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
T = np.linspace(T.min(),T.max(),T.size) # same range and size with a uniform interval
F = interp1d(T,X,fill_value='extrapolate') # resample the series on uniform interval
X = F(T) # Now it's resampled.
```

The essential issue is that `interp1d` does not accept an array `T` unless `T.size==X.size`.

Is there another method I can try to resample the time series `T,X` on uniform intervals of width `dt`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
dt = ...
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d   
Told = np.arange(T.min(),T.max(),T.size)
F = interp1d(Told,X,fill_value='extrapolate') 
Tnew = np.linspace(T.min(), T.max(), dt)
Xnew = F(Tnew)
```

Comment: oh, yeah, for sure. haha thank you! However I think `linspace` should be `arange`!

Comment: I agree with @kevinkayaks. dt is meant to be delta time between resampled points, so `np.arange()` is the proper function.

Comment: please add a few words on what the idea is in this solution.

Answer (score 0):

This was very useful for me.
Please note, however, that line

```
F = interp1d(Told,X,fill_value='extrapolate')
```

is not correct. It should read:'

```
F = interp1d(Told,X,kind='extrapolate')
```

or (in my case more useful):

```
F = interp1d(Told,X,kind='previous')
```

Comment: Thanks! I think the API may have actually changed in a recent scipy version. Just yesterday I realized some of my other interpolation scripts have quit working.